# Add item to list if condition is met until that list is a certain length (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a `list` of `id`s. I want to iterate over each one. For each one, I want to convert it to a `wid` in a dictionary (which it is definitely in), then I want to check if it is in a dictionary `wid_to_foo`. If it is, I want to add the key to a list until the list is a certain length; if it isn't, I want to go to the next `id`.

I am trying to do something like

```
[26648, 25207, 25203, 25208, 25201, 26298, 23675, 5721, 25008, 17001, 26013, 1973, 8751, 11052, 1468, 3007, 
10939, 6883, 17997, 15024, 25380, 21521, 20516, 22443, 18085, 3270, 12550, 16446, 3215, 25202, 3657, 46, 3980,
24031, 217, 2665, 912, 14048, 9925, 23494, 5397, 5138, 24103, 9932, 10766, 23869, 14448, 11860, 18103]

while len(list_three) < desired_len:
  try:
    list_three.append([wid_to_foo[id_to_wid[item]] for item in list_two])
  except KeyError:
    continue
```

I imagine I need to compare `while`, `for` and `try`, but I am not sure how to do it!

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean 'I imagine ...'? You are using `append()` which only appends a single item but then you have a list comprehension, which could have many items in it... perhaps you meant `list.extend()`

Comment: By "I imagine" I mean "I suspect, but I don't know how it would work." How would I do it without a list comprehension, please?

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to be a [mre] so i can paste it into a file and run it myself to get the same result as you. What result do you get? Btw stackoverflow isn’t a code writing service: you have to show an honest attempt to solve the problem, and that requires a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion comes from two competing conditions: "iterate a list" (a job for a `for` loop) and "until certain condition is met" (best with `while` loop). It seems to be easier to do with a `for` loop breaking on condition, rather than manually handling iteration within a while loop:

```
for item in list_two:
    try:
        list_three.append([wid_to_foo[id_to_wid[item]]
    except KeyError:
        continue
    if len(list_three) >= desired_len:
        break
```